# LTS 16.06: ubuntu-software do not list pigdin when pidgin is available in synaptic

Tags: software-center, pidgin

"Why pidgin is not proposed by ubuntu-software, when pidgin is listed in synaptic ?", is the question I have in mind after having installed a fresh and clean LTS 16.06 xenial UBUNTU from an checked ISO image burned on a DVD.

It is really strange, isn't it ? Does it mean there is something strong with my install ? with ubuntu-software ?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the cache, might have solved the problem. Just stop ubuntu-software or gnome-software, and remove the cache like this:

```
$ killall gnome-software
$ rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software
```